# Ignore Specific Field(s) on POJO in all mapping implementations Mapstruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, mapstruct

My persistent entities has fields `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `modifiedBy`, `modifiedAt`.
I would like mapstruct to **always** ignore mapping these fields, since they are autogenerated using hibernate annotations.
I don't like the idea of doing `@Mapping(target = ..., ignore = true)` repeatedly.

Is there a way to do this at the, for e.g. at my entity level, instead of the Mapper method level?
Or is there some other better solution than repeating the annotations?

bit more context - the mapping implementations use builders generated by lombok.
my entites can either extend `UpdatableEntity` or `BaseEntity`
all my entities, `UpdatableEntity` and `BaseEntity` use `@SuperBuilder`
`BaseEntity` has `createdBy` and `createdAt`
`UpdatableEntity` has `modifiedBy` and `modifiedAt` and extends `BaseEntity`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an option that is designed to globally disable certain fields for mapping.

There are 3 possible solutions that I can think of.

1. Use `@AfterMapping` to clear these fields afterwards.
2. Use Mapping composition to create an annotation containing all ignores.
3. Use a custom SPI to make the fields invalid options for mapping.

The 3rd one might be the closest to globally disabling fields for mapping, although this feature was intended to allow support for custom ways of defining getters/setters.

---

### `@AfterMapping` option

You can create an util class which you then include in all your mappers, for example:

```java
interface ClearTimeStampsUtil {
  @AfterMapping
  default void clearValues(@MappingTarget UpdatableEntity target) {
    target.setCreatedBy(null);
    // etc.
  }
}

@Mapper( uses = ClearTimeStampsUtil.class )
interface OneOfTheMappers {
    // mapping stuff.
}
```

---

### Mapping Composition option

You can collect all default mapping actions into a single annotation which is then used at all the mapping methods.

```java
@Mapping(target = ..., ignore = true)
...
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface DefaultMappingConfiguration { }

@Mapper
interface OneOfTheMappers {
  @DefaultMappingConfiguration
  ResultType map(SourceType source);
}
```

for more information see [Mapping composition documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition).

---

### Custom SPI

```java
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean isGetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        if (isIgnorableField(method)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isGetterMethod(method);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        if (isIgnorableField(method)) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isSetterMethod(method);
    }

    private boolean isIgnorableField(ExecutableElement method) {
        return getPropertyName(method).equals("createdBy")
            || getPropertyName(method).equals("createdAt")
            /*etc.*/;
    }
}
```

for more information see [Custom Accessor Naming Strategy in the SPI section](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-spi)

---

I hope that these options help you.